# Getting Error while trying to Retrieve Magento 2 orders using Rest API

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

I am trying to retrieve the Orders using REST API.
I want to retrieve all the processing orders for that i am using search criteria.
Below is what i have tried , but it is not working
[https://auto1.online/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&](https://auto1.online/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=status&)
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=processing&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq

I am getting error, see [image]

Answer (score 0):

This particular error is because you used `status` in `where` clause without specifying this `status` column belongs to which table. So, `table_name.status` should fix this very problem.

Comment: Did not get you. Can you please ellaborate? Do i need to change anything in the API?Which table name should it be?

Comment: Iff you're using some kind of join/where clauses while filtering your orders, there could be a field named `status` that is throwing SQL ambiguity error since query doesn't know which `status` to refer incase there are multiple tables with same named column : `status`. That's what this error literally mean.